# Indexing heavily nested json data in solr using DIH

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, solr, amazon-dynamodb

I using DIH to import the data from a NoSQL data source . The format looks something like below

```
{
  "id" : "123-145-app" 
  "name" : "apple",
  "type" : "electronic",
  "information": {
     "category":["tablets","laptops","mobile"],
     "stores": [ 
       {
         "name": "imagine",
         "location" : "DLH"
       },
       {
         "name": "abc",
         "location" : "BLR"
       }
      ],
      "head_office" : "US"
  }
}
```

when I try to index this using :
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html

I am getting error stating : "Unknown operation for the an atomic update, operation ignored" , and the record with that data is getting skipped.

And in the documentation they have not mentioned about how to incorporate the split via configuration file or schema.xml

Can some one please help me with this ?